# MediaWiki Setting a default group for new users

Tags: permissions, mediawiki, usergroups

I'm sure this has been answered somewhere but I can't find it after a few hours of searching. What I want to do is allow users to to create their own account but only be able to read until I give them the permissions to edit articles. I can figure out the part needed to create a new group but I'm having trouble telling it to give new users a specific group permission. I'm probably just not looking in the right places but if someone could help me out or at least point me in the right direction that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Usually, ConfirmAccount covers such use cases best. From your question it's not clear why you want them to get an account automatically, is it a private wiki?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing it the other way around: Give the default user group read only permission, and then elevate users to a trusted users group.

```
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['edit']             = false;
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['createpage']       = false;
$wgGroupPermissions['user']['edit']          = false;
$wgGroupPermissions['user']['createpage']    = false;
$wgGroupPermissions['trusted']['edit']       = true;
$wgGroupPermissions['trusted']['createpage'] = true;
```

Comment: yeah that's pretty much what i ended up doing. seems to work. thanks!